# JSON Array String to Json Array

Tags: java, android, json, exception, gson

I have a string as below that I receive from web service

```
[
    {
        "id": "AEC56A1C-E590-4CCE-B3DD-7AFF8FEE9216",
        "itemname": "tyuytuytuytuytutyu",
        "itemdescription": "hdfg dag dg sd gsg sdg sdg sg sgd",
        "itemprice": 40,
        "specialprice": 0,
        "itemimageurl": "no-url",
        "catid": "6A1A4E13-6AFD-44DD-998D-3A51E35C2C23",
        "status": true,
        "itemlongname": "yutyuyut",
        "iscombodeal": false
    },
    {
        "id": "E29249B2-E620-487C-9D66-1BC07A1B1D93",
        "itemname": "rrrr",
        "itemdescription": "rrrrr",
        "itemprice": 20,
        "specialprice": 0,
        "itemimageurl": "no-url",
        "catid": "6A1A4E13-6AFD-44DD-998D-3A51E35C2C23",
        "status": true,
        "itemlongname": "rrrr",
        "iscombodeal": false
    },
    {
        "id": "D273D888-0526-4487-8113-6405C8E216D5",
        "itemname": "vTD",
        "itemdescription": "vTDvTD",
        "itemprice": 0,
        "specialprice": 0,
        "itemimageurl": "no-url",
        "catid": "6A1A4E13-6AFD-44DD-998D-3A51E35C2C23",
        "status": true,
        "itemlongname": "vTD",
        "iscombodeal": false
    },
    {
        "id": "DF6DC5E3-25E9-4D57-89F4-C2BA8A719866",
        "itemname": "NO option",
        "itemdescription": "NO option",
        "itemprice": 45.78,
        "specialprice": 0,
        "itemimageurl": "no-url",
        "catid": "6A1A4E13-6AFD-44DD-998D-3A51E35C2C23",
        "status": true,
        "itemlongname": "NO option",
        "iscombodeal": false
    },
    {
        "id": "AD1739A6-B50A-4780-B71E-9E4E98AF19B5",
        "itemname": "ttttt",
        "itemdescription": "tttt",
        "itemprice": 12,
        "specialprice": 0,
        "itemimageurl": "no-url",
        "catid": "6A1A4E13-6AFD-44DD-998D-3A51E35C2C23",
        "status": true,
        "itemlongname": "tttttt",
        "iscombodeal": false
    },
    {
        "id": "C3206E79-BD92-4F49-B291-C57EB36AFCCC",
        "itemname": "Marinara (Seafood)",
        "itemdescription": "(Anchovies optional), shrimps, crab, mussels, squids, mozzarella",
        "itemprice": 0,
        "specialprice": 0,
        "itemimageurl": "no-url",
        "catid": "9960CA1F-46D3-4532-95E7-84F75B3771FE",
        "status": true,
        "itemlongname": "Marinara (Seafood)",
        "iscombodeal": false
    },
    {
        "id": "FD3603B9-1175-463F-A6AD-CCF1141E135D",
        "itemname": "Hawaiian",
        "itemdescription": "Double ham, double pineapple, mozzarella",
        "itemprice": 0,
        "specialprice": 0,
        "itemimageurl": "no-url",
        "catid": "9960CA1F-46D3-4532-95E7-84F75B3771FE",
        "status": true,
        "itemlongname": "Hawaiian",
        "iscombodeal": false
    },
    {
        "id": "9C34BAA6-85ED-4E49-A0A5-B99EF88472EC",
        "itemname": "Siliciana",
        "itemdescription": "Salami, onions, capsicum, mushroom, tomato, mozzarella",
        "itemprice": 0,
        "specialprice": 0,
        "itemimageurl": "no-url",
        "catid": "9960CA1F-46D3-4532-95E7-84F75B3771FE",
        "status": true,
        "itemlongname": "Siliciana (Olives optional)",
        "iscombodeal": false
    },
    {
        "id": "4E024FDF-46F1-4E91-A26F-468E3C7804A0",
        "itemname": "Hot Hot",
        "itemdescription": "Salami, onion, fresh garlic, chilli, parmesan cheese, mozzarella and jalapeno",
        "itemprice": 0,
        "specialprice": 0,
        "itemimageurl": "no-url",
        "catid": "9960CA1F-46D3-4532-95E7-84F75B3771FE",
        "status": true,
        "itemlongname": "Hot Hot",
        "iscombodeal": false
    },
    {
        "id": "C0EC7736-3AB1-4D52-AE47-97D01BEA8A9C",
        "itemname": "Meat Treat",
        "itemdescription": "(BBQ sauce optional) ham, salami, bacon, cabanossi, mozzarella",
        "itemprice": 0,
        "specialprice": 0,
        "itemimageurl": "no-url",
        "catid": "9960CA1F-46D3-4532-95E7-84F75B3771FE",
        "status": true,
        "itemlongname": "Meat Treat",
        "iscombodeal": false
    },
    {
        "id": "0B6E4A06-9865-4A88-AAFC-1C45F688B4C9",
        "itemname": "Pizza to Go Special",
        "itemdescription": "Ham, salami, onion, pineapple, mushrooms, capsicum, mozzarella",
        "itemprice": 0,
        "specialprice": 0,
        "itemimageurl": "no-url",
        "catid": "9960CA1F-46D3-4532-95E7-84F75B3771FE",
        "status": true,
        "itemlongname": "Pizza to Go Special",
        "iscombodeal": false
    },
    {
        "id": "E54F3F0B-7E07-4D6A-BAE4-6C8B8B87210D",
        "itemname": "Capriciosa",
        "itemdescription": "salami, mushroom, tomato and mozzarella",
        "itemprice": 0,
        "specialprice": 0,
        "itemimageurl": "no-url",
        "catid": "9960CA1F-46D3-4532-95E7-84F75B3771FE",
        "status": true,
        "itemlongname": "Capriciosa",
        "iscombodeal": false
    }
]
```

Now I'd like to change it to jArray (GSON libraray). Variable `itemsJsonString` is holding the string received via web service.

```
JsonArray jArray = new JsonArray();
JsonPrimitive element = new JsonPrimitive(gson.toJson(itemsJsonString));
jArray.add(element);
```

When I run above code I get Illegalstateexception not a jSON object error.

Here is a stack trace.

```
05-23 12:27:14.443: E/AndroidRuntime(26697): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
05-23 12:27:14.443: E/AndroidRuntime(26697): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.proitzen.pizzatogo/com.proitzen.pizzatogo.ItemActivity}: 

java.lang.IllegalStateException: Not a JSON Object: "\"[{\\\"id\\\":\\\"AEC56A1C-E590-4CCE-B3DD-7AFF8FEE9216\\\",\\\"itemname\\\":\\\"tyuytuytuytuytutyu\\\",\\\"itemdescription\\\":\\\"hdfg dag dg sd gsg sdg sdg sg sgd\\\",\\\"itemprice\\\":40,\\\"specialprice\\\":0,\\\"itemimageurl\\\":\\\"no-url\\\",\\\"catid\\\":\\\"6A1A4E13-6AFD-44DD-998D-3A51E35C2C23\\\",\\\"status\\\":true,\\\"itemlongname\\\":\\\"yutyuyut\\\",\\\"iscombodeal\\\":false},{\\\"id\\\":\\\"E29249B2-E620-487C-9D66-1BC07A1B1D93\\\",\\\"itemname\\\":\\\"rrrr\\\",\\\"itemdescription\\\":\\\"rrrrr\\\",\\\"itemprice\\\":20,\\\"specialprice\\\":0,\\\"itemimageurl\\\":\\\"no-url\\\",\\\"catid\\\":\\\"6A1A4E13-6AFD-44DD-998D-3A51E35C2C23\\\",\\\"status\\\":true,\\\"itemlongname\\\":\\\"rrrr\\\",\\\"iscombodeal\\\":false},{\\\"id\\\":\\\"D273D888-0526-4487-8113-6405C8E216D5\\\",\\\"itemname\\\":\\\"vTD\\\",\\\"itemdescription\\\":\\\"vTDvTD\\\",\\\"itemprice\\\":0,\\\"specialprice\\\":0,\\\"itemimageurl\\\":\\\"no-url\\\",\\\"catid\\\":\\\"6A1A4E13-6AFD-44DD-998D-3A51E35C2C23\\\",\\\"status\\\":true,\\\"itemlongname\\\":\\\"vTD\\\",\\\"iscombodeal\\\":false},{\\\"id\\\":\\\"DF6DC5E3-25E9-4D57-89F4-C2BA8A719866\\\",\\\"itemname\\\":\\\"NO option\\\",\\\"itemdescription\\\":\\\"NO option\\\",\\\"itemprice\\\":45.78,\\\"specialprice\\\":0,\\\"itemimageurl\\\":\\\"no-url\\\",\\\"catid\\\":\\\"6A1A4E13-6AFD-44DD-998D-3A51E35C2C23\\\",\\\"status\\\":true,\\\"itemlongname\\\":\\\"NO option\\\",\\\"iscombodeal\\\":false},{\\\"id\\\":\\\"AD1739A6-B50A-4780-B71E-9E4E98AF19B5\\\",\\\"itemname\\\":\\\"ttttt\\\",\\\"itemdescription\\\":\\\"tttt\\\",\\\"itemprice\\\":12,\\\"specialprice\\\":0,\\\"itemimageurl\\\":\\\"no-url\\\",\\\"catid\\\":\\\"6A1A4E13-6AFD-44DD-998D-3A51E35C2C23\\\",\\\"status\\\":true,\\\"itemlongname\\\":\\\"tttttt\\\",\\\"iscombodeal\\\":false},{\\\"id\\\":\\\"C3206E79-BD92-4F49-B291-C57EB36AFCCC\\\",\\\"itemname\\\":\\\"Marinara (Seafood)\\\",\\\"itemdescription\\\":\\\"(Anchovies optional), shrimps, crab, mussels, squids, mozzarella\\\",\\\"itemprice\\\":0,\\\"specialprice\\\":0,\\\"itemimageurl\\\":\\\"no-url\\\",\\\"catid\\\":\\\"9960CA1F-46D3-4532-95E7-84F75B3771FE\\\",\\\"status\\\":true,\\\"itemlongname\\\":\\\"Marinara (Seafood)\\\",\\\"iscombodeal\\\":false},{\\\"id\\\":\\\"FD3603B9-1175-463F-A6AD-CCF1141E135D\\\",\\\"itemname\\\":\\\"Hawaiian\\\",\\\"itemdescription\\\":\\\"Double ham, double pineapple, mozzarella\\\",\\\"itemprice\\\":0,\\\"specialprice\\\":0,\\\"itemimageurl\\\":\\\"no-url\\\",\\\"catid\\\":\\\"9960CA1F-46D3-4532-95E7-84F75B3771FE\\\",\\\"status\\\":true,\\\"itemlongname\\\":\\\"Hawaiian\\\",\\\"iscombodeal\\\":false},{\\\"id\\\":\\\"9C34BAA6-85ED-4E49-A0A5-B99EF88472EC\\\",\\\"itemname\\\":\\\"Siliciana\\\",\\\"itemdescription\\\":\\\"Salami, onions, capsicum, mushroom, tomato, mozzarella\\\",\\\"itemprice\\\":0,\\\"specialprice\\\":0,\\\"itemimageurl\\\":\\\"no-url\\\",\\\"catid\\\":\\\"9960CA1F-46D3-4532-95E7-84F75B3771FE\\\",\\\"status\\\":true,\\\"itemlongname\\\":\\\"Siliciana (Olives optional)\\\",\\\"iscombodeal\\\":false},{\\\"id\\\":\\\"4E024FDF-46F1-4E91-A26F-468E3C7804A0\\\",\\\"itemname\\\":\\\"Hot Hot\\\",\\\"itemdescription\\\":\\\"Salami, onion, fresh garlic, chilli, parmesan cheese, mozzarella and jalapeno\\\",\\\"itemprice\\\":0,\\\"specialprice\\\":0,\\\"itemimageurl\\\":\\\"no-url\\\",\\\"catid\\\":\\\"9960CA1F-46D3-4532-95E7-84F75B3771FE\\\",\\\"status\\\":true,\\\"itemlongname\\\":\\\"Hot Hot\\\",\\\"iscombodeal\\\":false},{\\\"id\\\":\\\"C0EC7736-3AB1-4D52-AE47-97D01BEA8A9C\\\",\\\"itemname\\\":\\\"Meat Treat\\\",\\\"itemdescription\\\":\\\"(BBQ sauce optional) ham, salami, bacon, cabanossi, mozzarella\\\",\\\"itemprice\\\":0,\\\"specialprice\\\":0,\\\"itemimageurl\\\":\\\"no-url\\\",\\\"catid\\\":\\\"9960CA1F-46D3-4532-95E7-84F75B3771FE\\\",\\\"status\\\":true,\\\"itemlongname\\\":\\\"Meat Treat\\\",\\\"iscombodeal\\\
```

rest of the strace is full of the json string

Could someone be able to help me out on this issue. I couldn't figure it out on my own last 3 days :(

Comment: why don't you are using a org.json inbuilt in android

Comment: I'm using Azure Mobile services. GSON is packed with it.

Comment: Gson is basically design to convert json response in POJO classes. Otherwise org.json is ok

Comment: @BirajZalavadia do you think I can extract the data using json ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do this way

You can easily parse json using org.json

```
try {
            JSONArray jArray = new JSONArray(responseString);
            int size= jArray.length();
            for (int i = 0; i < size; i++) {
                JSONObject item= jArray.getJSONObject(i);
                System.out.println("id : " + item.getString("id"));
                System.out.println("itemname : " + item.getString("itemname"));
                System.out.println("itemdescription : " + item.getString("itemdescription"));

                    // ........ so on 

            }
        } catch (Exception e) {
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to put `.replaceAll("\\\","")` in your code wherever your code is. Its your choice. :))

Answer (score -1):

You can parse your json using this method

```
public static ArrayList parseJSON(String url, int method,List<NameValuePair> params, Class classType) {

    ArrayList list = new ArrayList();
    StrictMode.enableDefaults();
    StrictMode.ThreadPolicy policy = new StrictMode.ThreadPolicy.Builder()
            .permitAll().build();
    StrictMode.setThreadPolicy(policy);
    String respo = "";
    try {
        DefaultHttpClient httpClient = new DefaultHttpClient();

        HttpResponse httpResponse = null;

        if (method == POST) {

            HttpPost httpPost = new HttpPost(url);

            // adding post params
            if (params != null) {
                httpPost.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(params));
            }

            httpResponse = httpClient.execute(httpPost);

        } else if (method == GET) {
            // appending params to url
            if (params != null) {
                String paramString = URLEncodedUtils
                        .format(params, "utf-8");
                url += "?" + paramString;
            }
            HttpGet httpGet = new HttpGet(url);

            httpResponse = httpClient.execute(httpGet);

        }

        StatusLine statusLine = httpResponse.getStatusLine();

        int statuscode = statusLine.getStatusCode();
        Log.v("Pre School App", "Response code = " + statuscode);

        if (statuscode == 200) {
            HttpEntity entity = httpResponse.getEntity();
            respo = EntityUtils.toString(entity);
            Log.e("Pre School App test ", "Status code = " + respo);
        } else {
            Log.e("Pre School App test ", "Status code = " + respo);
        }

        // HttpEntity entity = httpResponse.getEntity();
        // respo = EntityUtils.toString(entity);

    } catch (Exception e) {
        // Toast.makeText(myContext, "Error !" + e,
        // Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    if (classType != null) {
        try {
            JSONArray jArray = new JSONArray(respo);
            for (int i = 0; i < jArray.length(); i++) {
                JSONObject json = jArray.getJSONObject(i);
                Gson gson = new Gson();
                list.add(gson.fromJson(json.toString(), classType));

            }
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    } else {
        return null;
    }
    return list;
}
```